# Unable to extend django template properly?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a `base.html` template which contains basic html definitions .The other templates are defined below

```
// pages/dashboard.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'components/nav.html' %}
    {% include 'components/dashboard.html' %}
{% endblock %}

// components/dashboard.html
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="main-page">
        {% block dashboard %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>

// mailer/new.html
{% extends 'pages/dashboard.html' %}
{% block dashboard %}
    <h1>hello</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

The view renders `mailer/new.html` the problem is that the block containing `<h1>hello</h1>` is not working. Where am i going wrong with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% include %}` doesn't work that way. See the note in the [documentation for that tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> Blocks are evaluated *before* they are included. This means that a template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that have *already been evaluated and rendered* - not blocks that can be overridden by, for example, an extending template.